# Questions about the performance of different implementations of strlen

Tags: performance, gcc, sse, inline-assembly, intrinsics

I have implemented the `strlen()` function in different ways, including `SSE2 assembly`, `SSE4.2 assembly` and `SSE2 intrinsic`, I also exerted some experiments on them, with `strlen() in <string.h>` and `strlen() in glibc`. However, their performance in terms of milliseconds (time) are unexpected.

My experiment environment:
`CentOS 7.0 + gcc 4.8.5 + Intel Xeon`

Following are my implementations:

1. `strlen` using SSE2 assembly

   ```
   long strlen_sse2_asm(const char* src){
   long result = 0;
   asm(
       "movl %1, %%edi\n\t"
       "movl $-0x10, %%eax\n\t"
       "pxor %%xmm0, %%xmm0\n\t"
       "lloop:\n\t"
           "addl $0x10, %%eax\n\t"
           "movdqu (%%edi,%%eax), %%xmm1\n\t"
           "pcmpeqb %%xmm0, %%xmm1\n\t"
           "pmovmskb %%xmm1, %%ecx\n\t"
           "test %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
           "jz lloop\n\t"

       "bsf %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
       "addl %%ecx, %%eax\n\t"
       "movl %%eax, %0"
       :"=r"(result)
       :"r"(src)
       :"%eax"
       );
   return result;
   }
   ```

2.`strlen` using SSE4.2 assembly

```
long strlen_sse4_2_asm(const char* src){
long result = 0;
asm(
    "movl %1, %%edi\n\t"
    "movl $-0x10, %%eax\n\t"
    "pxor %%xmm0, %%xmm0\n\t"
    "lloop2:\n\t"
        "addl $0x10, %%eax\n\t"
        "pcmpistri $0x08,(%%edi, %%eax), %%xmm0\n\t"
        "jnz lloop2\n\t"

        "add %%ecx, %%eax\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %0"

    :"=r"(result)
    :"r"(src)
    :"%eax"
    );
return result;
}
```

3. `strlen` using SSE2 intrinsic

```
long strlen_sse2_intrin_align(const char* src){
if (src == NULL || *src == '\0'){
    return 0;
}
const __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
const __m128i* ptr = (const __m128i*)src;

if(((size_t)ptr&0xF)!=0){
    __m128i xmm = _mm_loadu_si128(ptr);
    unsigned int mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(xmm,zero));
    if(mask!=0){
        return (const char*)ptr-src+(size_t)ffs(mask);
    }
    ptr = (__m128i*)(0x10+(size_t)ptr & ~0xF);
}
for (;;ptr++){
    __m128i xmm = _mm_load_si128(ptr);
    unsigned int mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(xmm,zero));
    if (mask!=0)
        return (const char*)ptr-src+(size_t)ffs(mask);
}

}
```

4. I also looked up the one implemented in linux kernel， following is its implementation

   ```
   size_t strlen_inline_asm(const char* str){
   int d0;
   size_t res;
   asm volatile("repne\n\t"
   "scasb"
   :"=c" (res), "=&D" (d0)
   : "1" (str), "a" (0), "" (0xffffffffu)
   : "memory");

   return ~res-1;
   }
   ```

In my experience, I also added the one of standard library and compared their performance.
Followings are my `main` function code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
int main()
{
    struct timeval tpstart,tpend;
    int i=0;
    for(;i<1023;i++){
            test_str[i] = 'a';
    }
    test_str[i]='\0';
    gettimeofday(&tpstart,NULL);
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
            strlen(test_str);
    gettimeofday(&tpend,NULL);
    printf("strlen from stirng.h--->%lf\n",(tpend.tv_sec-tpstart.tv_sec)*1000+(tpend.tv_usec-tpstart.tv_usec)/1000.0);

    gettimeofday(&tpstart,NULL);
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
            strlen_inline_asm(test_str);
    gettimeofday(&tpend,NULL);
    printf("strlen_inline_asm--->%lf\n",(tpend.tv_sec-tpstart.tv_sec)*1000+(tpend.tv_usec-tpstart.tv_usec)/1000.0);

    gettimeofday(&tpstart,NULL);
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
            strlen_sse2_asm(test_str);
    gettimeofday(&tpend,NULL);
    printf("strlen_sse2_asm--->%lf\n",(tpend.tv_sec-tpstart.tv_sec)*1000+(tpend.tv_usec-tpstart.tv_usec)/1000.0);

    gettimeofday(&tpstart,NULL);
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
            strlen_sse4_2_asm(test_str);
    gettimeofday(&tpend,NULL);
    printf("strlen_sse4_2_asm--->%lf\n",(tpend.tv_sec-tpstart.tv_sec)*1000+(tpend.tv_usec-tpstart.tv_usec)/1000.0);

    gettimeofday(&tpstart,NULL);
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++)
            strlen_sse2_intrin_align(test_str);
    gettimeofday(&tpend,NULL);
    printf("strlen_sse2_intrin_align--->%lf\n",(tpend.tv_sec-tpstart.tv_sec)*1000+(tpend.tv_usec-tpstart.tv_usec)/1000.0);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is : (ms)

```
strlen from stirng.h--->23.518000
strlen_inline_asm--->222.311000
strlen_sse2_asm--->782.907000
strlen_sse4_2_asm--->955.960000
strlen_sse2_intrin_align--->3499.586000
```

I have some questions about it:

1. Why `strlen` of `string.h` is so fast? I think its code should be identify to `strlen_inline_asm` because I copied the code from `/linux-4.2.2/arch/x86/lib/string_32.c`[http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/arch/x86/lib/string_32.c#L164]
2. Why `sse2 intrinsic` and `sse2 assembly` are so different in performance?
3. Could someone help me how to disassembly the code so that I can see what has the function `strlen` of static library been transformed by the compiler? I used `gcc -s` but didn't find the disassembly of `strlen from the <string.h>`
4. I think my code may be not very well, I would be appreciate if you could help me improve my code, especially assembly ones.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it benchmarks a standard, pure function by throwing away the result in a loop.

Comment: Do you mean there is something wrong with my experiments? Could you please figure it out?@Pascal Cuoq

Comment: The compiler probably optimizes away the `string.h` `strlen`, because it knows that it does (and that the result will be the same every time).  Did you check the asm output of the test loop?  Writing microbenchmarks that measure what you actually want to measure is non-trivial.

Comment: Also, your inline-asm version has a bunch of excess instructions to get operands in and out.  You could just use the output operand as your loop counter / `bsf` destination.  `movl %1, %%edi` is also pointless.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks, but I didn't use any optimization options  I just use `gcc -m32`

Comment: @BecomeBetter: You can't expect useful benchmark results with `-O0`.  I was wondering if that was the case, from how badly the intrinsics version performed.  Did you even look at the asm that gets generated from intrinsics with `-O0`?

Comment: @BecomeBetter: Also, you should mention the size/s of the test strings you're using - if they're sane/realistic (e.g. up to about 100 characters like is typical for normal code) then you'll get very different results to "insanely large" strings that are never used in sensible code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it benchmarks without optimizations.

Comment: The down-voting and vote-to-close on this question is throwing the baby out with the bathwater. Some of the benchmarking premises may be wrong, but if you lack the knowledge to critically examine the SSE implementations - you should just move on. There's plenty in this question worth considering and balancing with questions of string length, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Like I said in comments, your biggest error is benchmarking with `-O0`.  I discussed exactly why testing with `-O0` is a terrible idea [in the first part of another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/c-loop-optimization-help-for-final-assignment/32001196#32001196).

Benchmarks *should* be done with at least -O2, preferably with the same optimizations as your full project will build with, if you're trying to test test what source makes the fastest asm.

`-O0` explains inline asm being way faster than C with intrinsics (or regular compiled C, for C strlen implementation borrowed from glibc).

IDK `-O0` would still optimize away loop that discards the result of library strlen repeatedly, or if it somehow just avoided some other huge performance pitfall.  It's not interesting to guess about exactly what happened in such a flawed test.

---

**I tightened up your SSE2 inline-asm version**.  Mostly just because I've been playing with gcc inline asm input/output constraints recently, and wanted to see what it would look like if I wrote it to let the compiler choose which registers to use for temporaries, and avoided unneeded instructions.

The same inline asm works for 32 and 64-bit x86 targets; see this compiled for both [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z: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%2Bbs%2BaXcsje31r1vTpBABrPsxlOTjORseDwh7%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%2BvFhkwRVJRYQFmtUhl8wAOTRcV/mE2aWF5GY%2BSCsY60J4mjJMsz3HXZmZmlJh3GassQr59oAlmeYFEWWhCtaGIfnXJ25V5SHDp92w0hPGwpFJBhpFNKRSBYaRLA71BpE0fh%2BA8URxDrORaA7ghu%2Bb0l1xAWRZGMBfl5X1fCsYaQABYO67qQe9IPupA7wQQBfKe9%2Bb0g4FgJA0DBPBvDIChvvvx%2BQGAU1ZBfYTniGE%2BIFFNPUgLkWBxF5NICepA76cgIAAeT2uAi%2BpAsA8jYN4IB%2BAJjUjwN5IBbsqSHEkFISBgxW7EMnkYHQEDL7MDYCgQevBGB4FwvAUkxwCB4B%2BtIYYBlibDFgbIVQwwADqc0GBCJ5OIMwDRYiCGxgwcRwwdDM2GEwckBlhjtFxqKVAARVGhGPiPCQdAW5tx3kAw%2Bip4SFWGIVTedtiamiXpsXAhAujjzJJoVAr8pTj2GgPXg/BJ7T2SLPeei9V6ROXuvMh29O4WOkMfU%2BpBz491JNfRAKBvG9AfkMcglA745Lfh/L%2BpAf4tn/oApBICwHUKgd4mB8CGCIP3ig1gwB0FIMwblHBhY8HKmQIQuppC6mGF0NQlu7T6GBMYftFhkA2G9A4VwqQEinJCN4UIgRQjREKIkXEGIrxZHyMUco1Aqj1FCK0UMHReiDSGLEMYlqG8pDt3iUgyx1jbH2NjqoJxgiICuKIP9DxqgvE%2BJBVwJy/iGE8GCRfUJpA54LyXlEyJLy4m733ofJJZ8QmmKkFwcxHzEkpPxaQXGDgiggE3kAA%3D).  When compiling to a stand-along function, it doesn't have to save/restore any registers even in 32bit mode:

**WARNING: it can read past the end of the string by up to 15 bytes.  This could segfault.** See [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64) for details on avoiding that: get to an alignment boundary, then use aligned loads because that's always safe if the vector contains at least 1 byte of string data.  I left the code unchanged because it's interesting to discuss the effect of aligning pointers for SSE vs. AVX.  Aligning pointers also avoids cache-line splits, and 4k page-splits (which are a performance pothole before Skylake).

```
#include <immintrin.h>

size_t strlen_sse2_asm(const char* src){

  // const char *orig_src = src; // for a pointer-increment with a "+r" (src) output operand

  size_t result = 0;
  unsigned int tmp1;
  __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128(), vectmp;

  // A pointer-increment may perform better than an indexed addressing mode
  asm(
    "\n.Lloop:\n\t"
        "movdqu   (%[src], %[res]), %[vectmp]\n\t"  // result reg is used as the loop counter
        "pcmpeqb  %[zerovec], %[vectmp]\n\t"
        "pmovmskb %[vectmp], %[itmp]\n\t"
        "add      $0x10, %[res]\n\t"
        "test     %[itmp], %[itmp]\n\t"
        "jz  .Lloop\n\t"

    "bsf %[itmp], %[itmp]\n\t"
    "add %q[itmp], %q[res]\n\t"   // q modifier to get quadword register.
    // (add %edx, %rax doesn't work).  But in 32bit mode, q gives a 32bit reg, so the same code works
    : [res] "+r"(result), [vectmp] "=&x" (vectmp), [itmp] "=&r" (tmp1)

    : [zerovec] "x" (zero) // There might already be a zeroed vector reg when inlining
      , [src] "r"(src)
      , [dummy] "m" (*(const char (*)[])src) // this reads the whole object, however long gcc thinks it is
    : //"memory"        // not needed because of the dummy input
    );
  return result;
  // return result + tmp1;  // doing the add outside the asm makes gcc sign or zero-extend tmp1.
  // No benefit anyway, since gcc doesn't know that tmp1 is the offset within a 16B chunk or anything.
}
```

**Note the dummy input**, as an alternative to a `"memory"` clobber, to tell the compiler that the inline asm reads the memory pointed to by `src`, as well as the value of `src` itself.  (The compiler doesn't know what the asm does; for all it knows the asm just aligns a pointer with `and` or something, so assuming that all input pointers are dereferenced would lead to missed optimizations from reordering / combining loads and stores across the asm.  Also, this lets the compiler know we only read the memory, not modify it.)  The GCC manual [uses an example with this unspecified-length array syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers-1) `"m" (*(const char (*)[])src)`

It should keep register pressure to a minimum when inlining, and doesn't tie up any special-purpose registers (like `ecx` which is needed for variable-count shifts).

If you could shave another uop out of the inner loop, it would be down to 4 uops that could issue at one per cycle.  As it is, 5 uops means each iteration may take 2 cycles to issue from the frontend, on Intel SnB CPUs.  ([Or 1.25 cycles on later CPUs like Haswell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311872/is-performance-reduced-when-executing-loops-whose-uop-count-is-not-a-multiple-of), and maybe on SnB if I was wrong about the whole-number behaviour.)

**Using an aligned pointer would allow the load to fold into a memory operand for `pcmpeqb`**.  (As well as being necessary for correctness if the string start is unaligned and the end is near the end of a page).  Interestingly, using the zero-vector as the destination for `pcmpeqb` is ok in theory: you don't need to re-zero the vector between iterations, because you exit the loop if it's ever non-zero.  It has 1-cycle latency, so turning the zero vector into a loop-carried dependency is only a problem when cache-misses delay an old iteration.  Removing this loop-carried dependency chain might help in practice, though, by letting the back end go faster when catching up after a cache miss that delayed an old iteration.

AVX solves the problem completely (except for correctness if the string ends near the end of a page).  AVX allows the load to be folded even without doing an alignment check first.  3-operand non-destructive `vpcmpeqb` avoids turning the zero vector into a loop-carried dependency.  AVX2 would allow checking 32B at once.

**Unrolling will help either way, but helps more without AVX**.  Align to a 64B boundary or something, and then load the whole cache line into four 16B vectors.  Doing a combined check on the result of `POR`ing them all together may be good, since `pmovmsk` + `compare-and-branch` is 2 uops.

Using SSE4.1 `PTEST` doesn't help (compared to `pmovmsk` / `test` / `jnz`) because it's 2 uops and can't macro-fuse the way `test` can.

`PTEST` can directly test for the whole 16B vector being all-zero or all-ones (using ANDNOT -> CF part), but not if one of the byte-elements is zero.  (So we can't avoid `pcmpeqb`).

---

Have a look at [Agner Fog's guides](http://agner.org/optimize/) for optimizing asm, and the other links on the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki.  Most optimization (Agner Fog's, and Intel's and AMD's) will mention optimizing memcpy and strlen specifically, IIRC.

Comment: It occurs to me that this Q&A would have earned you both gold stars five years ago.

Comment: @BrettHale: /me, tilting at windmills since ... IDK when :P

Comment: No memory clobber?  Also, I wouldn't recommend tilting at windmills these days.  Those suckers are [HUGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestas_V164#Specifications).  You are better off going after dragons.  While dragons breathe fire, windmills have lawyers...

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: well spotted; I didn't notice that problem when re-reading the code I wrote a couple years ago, only spotted the alignment issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the source of the strlen function in the glibc, you can see that the function is not testing the string char by char, but longword by longword with complex bitwise operations : http://www.stdlib.net/~colmmacc/strlen.c.html. I guess it explains its speed, but the fact that it's even faster than rep instructions in assembly is indeed quite surprising.

Comment: `rep movs` / `rep stos` are fast on Intel.  `rep scas` / `rep cmps` are *NOT* fast.  They're slower than normal loops that go a byte at a time.

Comment: I added the glibc implementation, it isn't very fast compared with others in my experimentsstrlen `from stirng.h--->23.747000
strlen_inline_asm--->221.661000
strlen_sse2_asm--->797.489000
strlen_sse4_2_asm--->923.677000
strlen_sse2_intrin_align--->3467.068000
strlen of glib--->6591.779000`

Comment: Ok, guess the mystery's still intact.

Comment: @KeylorSanchez: Not really; I'm not surprised that compiling glibc's implementation with `-O0` gives garbage results.

Comment: Would it be compiled with -O3 or -Ofast then ? Would that explain such results ?

Comment: Benchmarks *should* be done with at least -O2, preferably with the same optimizations as your full project will build with, if you're trying to test test what source makes the fastest asm.  `-O0` *does* explain these results: intrinsics *way* slower than inline asm.  `-O0` may still optimize away library strlen, or maybe it's just inlined or something.  IDK about that, but I'm not interested in guessing about exactly what happened in such a flawed test.