# IA 32 AT&T - How to reach the end of a char array without dimension?

Tags: arrays, pointers, assembly, char, arguments

I have a function in C that is supposed to find how many 'X' are in a given char array.
I receive the array in the argument, but i do not receive its length

So in C it would be

```
countX(char ss[]){
   int i=0; cont=0;
   while(ss[i]!='/0'){
      if(ss[i]=='X') cont++;
      i++;
   }
   return cont;
   }
}
```

I have to implement this in asssembly but since i do not have the length of the array, i do not know what value do i need to compare in cmp instruction to reach the end of the char array?

Comment: `'/0'` looks like a typo. Should be `'\0'` for the NUL terminating character which also denotes the end. That assumes you are dealing with C strings

Comment: Character arrays in C don't automatically terminate with '\0', so I'm not sure that's a good comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and I did notice it was incorrect, it should be '\0'. Even though I agree with you, that code was given in a class exercise, so I will have to deal with it, no matter the circumstances.

Comment: If the code you posted was given to you by your lecturer then the typo would need to be fixed. The code suggests that the array is NUL (0) terminated. You will have to scan for both the value 0 (end of the string) and for the letter 'X'.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd If they represent strings, that's a perfectly valid assumption to make.

Comment: Note that you can easily implement this function using `rep scasb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is called `strlen`.  It's a search for the first `0` byte.

It only works if the array ends with a terminating `0` byte, i.e. it's an implicit-length C string.

There's no magic here, just loop until you find a `0` byte.

This is why `strlen` is slow compared to explicit-length strings that are pointer+length.  (Real `libc` implementations of `strlen` are optimized with hand-written asm to check 16 or 32 bytes at once, though.  See [Questions about the performance of different implementations of strlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449407/questions-about-the-performance-of-different-implementations-of-strlen), and [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64)).

---

For things other than strings, it's much more common to pass a pointer+length to a function, e.g. `void foo(float *arr, size_t len);`.